# I'm looking for an elegant way to create a vector of tuple_element from a vector of tuple

Tags: c++

```
typedef std::tuple<A, B, C> TUPLE;
typedef std::vector<TUPLE> TUPLE_VECTOR;
typedef std::vector<A> A_VECTOR;
```

I would like to find the most elegant way of creating an A_VECTOR from a TUPLE_VECTOR.

Comment: [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a lambda? Or [std::copy_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)?

Comment: I removed the second question from your question as you should only ask a single question per question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to copy just the `A`'s out of a `TUPLE_VECTOR`.  That would look like

```
TUPLE_VECTOR tuples;
A_VECTOR a_vector;
a_vector.reserve(tuples.size());
std::transform(tuples.begin(), tuples.end(), std::back_inserter(a_vector),
               [](const auto& tuple){ return std::get<A>(tuple); }); // can also use std::get<0>(tuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following has the advantage, that it can be used to initialize base-class/member objects...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>


typedef std::tuple<int, double> pair;
typedef std::vector<pair> pairVector;
typedef std::vector<int> intVector;

int main()
{   const pairVector sPairs{{0, 1.0}, {2, 3.0}, {4, 5.0}};
    typedef boost::transform_iterator<
            std::function<const int&(const pair&)>,
            pairVector::const_iterator,
            const int&,
            const int*
    > transIt;
    const std::function<const int&(const pair&)> sF(
            static_cast<const int&(*)(const pair&)>(
                    std::get<std::size_t(0), int, double>
            )
    );
    const intVector sFirsts(
            transIt(
                    sPairs.begin(),
                    sF
            ),
            transIt(
                    sPairs.end(),
                    sF
            )
    );
}
```